# Polymer 1.x: Imperatively adding event listener

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have added an event listener to my custom element for my `<iron-ajax>` call.

## Question

> Is there a shorter (more convenient syntax) way to ***imperatively*** (i.e., using Javascript) add the event listener in Polymer?

In other words, does the Polymer library contain any syntax sugaring for this?

custom-element.html

```
<template>
  ...
  <iron-ajax id="ajax" last-response="{{ajax}}"></iron-ajax>
  ...
<template>
<script>
  ...
  var that = this,
  t = this.$.ajax;
  t.addEventListener('response', function(e) {
    console.log(that.ajax);
  });
  ...
</script>
```

### Research

[The documentation here says](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#event-listeners):

> You can also add an event listener to any element in the `this.$` collection using the syntax `nodeId.eventName`.

But I think this only applies when using the `listeners` property in the Polymer object as in:

```
listeners: {
  'tap': 'regularTap',
  'special.tap': 'specialTap'
},
```

Comment: Side note: it looks like listening for `a.b` in `listeners` is a [target for deprecation](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/events.html#L58).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should work in JS as well (only tried in Dart)

```
 this.listen(this.$.ajax, 'last-response', 'lastResponseHandler');
```

there is also `this.unlisten()` to cancel the event subscription.
I assume that if you add it imperatively, you also need to remove it imperatively to prevent memory leaks.

References:

- [listen](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#Polymer.Base:method-listen)
- [unlisten](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#Polymer.Base:method-unlisten)

Comment: Yes, this is the only sugar I see in the [source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/events.html).

Comment: A common pattern is to use `listen` in `attached` and `unlisten` in `detached`. (Not sure that's necessary if you're only listening to events from your own local DOM, as opposed to document-level events, but it's probably not a bad idea.)

The callback is called with the element instance as the `this` value, so you don't need to use the extra variable in the original example.